# Replace image with any other image when user tap on any image in IPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4, ios-simulator

I am creating a application to learn IPhone application development. It will look like http://i52.tinypic.com/2ah8k7o.png that. Now i want when user tap on any image then the tapped image will replace by any other image. How can i do that.

I am just drag and dropping the images and labels from library to xib file. Is it correct way to draw that look or should i use any other way to draw that look and feel.

Comment: have use UItapGesturerecognizer? see this link http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008904

Comment: in this link u will get idea how attach tap on image and function of tap. in function of tap instead of zoom u show image view

Answer (score 2):

You should place your images into UIImageView. After this check user taps and simply change `image` property in UIImageView to new image.

Code like this (in your viewController, for example)

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
UIView *imgView = [[touches anyObject] view];
if ([view isKindOfClass:UIImageView.class]){
    UIImage *newImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"newImg.png"]; // newImg.png should be in bundle
    [(UIImageView*)view setImage:newImg];
}
```

}